# Vue3 template, short path to nested object property

Tags: templates, vuejs3

How to prepare a property for template? This code throws an error:

```
<script setup>
  ...
  const props = defineProps<{ datails: TData }>();
  const value = props.datails.value; // i dont want to use long paths in the template
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <a>{{ value }}</a>
...
```

The error:
`error  Getting a value from the 'props' in root scope of`  `will cause the value to lose reactivity  vue/no-setup-props-destructure`

So how to short paths for data binding in the template please?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you quickly convert props to refs:

```
<script setup>
  import { toRefs } from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps({ details: String });
  
  const { details } = toRefs(props);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <a>{{ details }}</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the error you are getting could be prevented by just by writing `ref(props.datails.value)` so the object won't loose reactivity.

Watch out for the usage of [defineProps](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits)